# how do i see actual message when hover over message?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, symfony1

excerpt of my listSuccess.php:

```
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $msg)
{ 
   //listing the messages' subjects here
   <a href="<?php echo url_for('messagebox/read?cursor=').$cursor ?>" style='color:#ff0000 !important' onmouseover="document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'none'" class='spn_small_red_rbc'><?php echo $msg->getSubject();?></a>
   <div id="hiddenDiv" style="display: none">Show the actual message here</div>
}
```

the above is not working though
any help please?
thanks

Comment: It would help if you gave more details when describing what it is you want to do.  I'm not sure what "see actual message when hover over message" means - which message?  Is it an image or text?  Where does the full data come from?  Would it be generated server-side or client-side?  Where/how do you want the "actual message" rendered - in a pop-up, a floating div, replacing the text in another part of the document?  Etc.

Comment: ...and to follow the edit, how is it "not working"?  That explanation doesn't allow people to solve the problem.  What output do you *expect*, and what do you actually get?

Comment: yikes sorry..please see edit the message is text...floating div i guess? thanks

Comment: sorry but have no idea how this works or if it is possible...i have a list showing the subject lines of each message in the foreach( as a link) so when you click on the link you can read the actual message. what i want is: when i hover over the link the actual message text must show/pop up.... sort of as a preview of the message...then when i click on the link i go to the actual message...hope this is better..sorry bout that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jQuery TOOLS for tooltip, it's well documented, works straightforward and is rich featured.

You can read docu and study demos here : http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Beside, @Baszz solution will work too, i would suggest the symfony solution with the javascript helper's function

```
<?php javascript_tag(); ?>

    // please study http://api.jquery.com/ready/
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        // Example for jQuery TOOLS tooltip
        jQuery(".spn_small_red_rbc").tooltip();
    });

<?php end_javascript_tag(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks i will read up on this

Answer (score 0):

Cleanup your code first and extract the styling and scripting. This makes it all more readable (using jQuery):

```
<style>
    a.spn_small_red_rbc { color: #ff0000; }
    div .hiddenDiv { display: none; }
</style>

<script>
    $('a.spn_small_red_rbc').hover(function(){
       // Mouse enter
       $(this).next('div').show();
    },
    function(){
       // Mouse leave
       $(this).next('div').hide();
    });
</script>

<? foreach ($pager->getResults() as $msg) { ?>
    <a href="<?=url_for('messagebox/read?cursor=').$cursor?>" class="spn_small_red_rbc"><?=$msg->getSubject()?></a>
    <div id="hiddenDiv">Show the actual message here</div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: thank you i cleaned it up, the <a href> shows correct, but the div also shows underneath, i only want thet to show when i hover over the above link please? thank you

Comment: i tried that and is still shows the div regardless. it seems it doesnt recognize the  "$('a.spn_small_red_rbc').hover(function()" part cos i added a console.log just after this line and it did not display. but thanks i will read @domi27's doc and try and figure it out. thanks